# Can we say that : $ (A-B)\cap\overline{B}(0,r)\text{ is weakly compact, }\forall r>0 $

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and $A,B$ are closed convex subsets of $X$ such that $B\subset A$ and 
$$
A\cap\overline{B}(0,r) \text{ and } B\cap\overline{B}(0,r) \text{ are weakly compact, } \forall r>0.
$$

Can we say that : 
$$
(A-B)\cap\overline{B}(0,r)\text{ is weakly compact, }\forall r>0
$$
with $A-B=\{a-b:a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Comment: No I made a mistake, I have to write $ B\subset A $.

Comment: I did not understand why  $(A-B)\cap \overline{B}(0,r)$ probably is not closed?

Comment: Why $ (A−B)\cap\overline{B(0,r)}$ is relatively open in the convex?

Comment: Can you explain what you say in a few lines

Comment: @LSpice: $A-B$ is NOT set theoretic difference--look at the OP's definition. This is a reasonable question for MO.

Comment: @BillJohnson, thank you for [correcting my misreading](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359778/can-we-say-that-a-b-cap-overlineb0-r-text-is-weakly-compact-forall#comment906172_359778).  @‍kakaHae, I apologise for misreading your question.  I retracted my close vote, and will delete my inadvertently misleading comments.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this already fail in finite dimensions? Take $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $A = B =$
the closed region bounded by $y = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ and $y = x + 1$, both for $x \geq 0$. The intersection with any ball is closed and therefore compact, but $A - B$ is not closed: it contains points arbitrarily close to $(0, -1)$ but does not contain that point itself.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking the OP meant in the conclusion, in which case there is no counterexample in reflexive spaces. I now see a counterexample with  "relatively weakly compact" but won't bother to add it if the OP did mean "weakly compact". @kakaHae: If you did mean "relatively weakly compact", please add this at the end of your question. Do not change the question as asked because that renders much of the discussion gibberish for anyone who does look at the edits to the question.

Comment: @BillJohnson I'm confused by your comment. Are you saying that in my example $A - B$ is not weakly compact but is relatively weakly compact? Or its intersection with every ball is weakly compact but not relatively weakly compact? It's not even closed, so I'm not sure what that could mean.

Comment: Not $A-B$, Nik, but $A-B$ intersected with every ball is what the OP is looking at. I thought the OP wanted relative weak compactness of $A-B$ intersected with balls, but I saw after your answer that he asked for weak compactness of $A-B$ intersected with closed balls. The version asking for relative weak compactness is a nice question, while, as you point out, what the OP asked is basically trivial.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, that is an interesting misreading of the question ...

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but I put it here to stop close votes that are apparently based on a misreading of the question.

I do not know the answer to the OP's question, but I will point out that both hypotheses are necessary. For example, drop the hypothesis that $A$ is convex. Then there is a counterexample with $A=B$; namely, $A=\bigcup_n \{(n+1)e_n, ne_n\}$, where $(e_n)$ is the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$. Bounded subsets of $A$ are finite and $A-A$ contains $(e_n)$, which is not preweakly compact.

Secondly, drop the hypothesis that $B\subset A$ but keep the convexity hypotheses. Let $X= C[0,1]$ ($X$ could be any separable non reflexive space that contains an infinite dimensional reflexive subspace). It is known that there are quasi complementary subspaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ that are both isomorphic to $\ell_2$. This means that $X_1 \cap X_2 =\{0\}$ and $X_1 - X_2$ is norm dense in $X$, and hence $(X_1 - X_2) \cap B(0,1)$ is even norm dense in the non weakly compact unit ball of $X$.

Comment: @Bill_Johnson Thank you sir

Comment: Another way to achieve the conclusion as in the second half of Bill‘s answer: Take a reflexive $X$ and two closed subspaces $A$ and $B$ whose sum $Z=A+B=A-B$ is not closed and dense. Then the unit ball of $Z$ is not weakly compact, being a norm and weakly dense proper subset of the unit ball of $X$.